# constant 'error' used before being initialized

Tags: ios, swift, error-handling, constants, avaudiorecorder

I am detecting microphone blow and using this to trigger an animation and am getting this error message. "constant 'error' used before being intialised". This is the code I have:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //make an AudioSession, set it to PlayAndRecord and make it active
    let audioSession:AVAudioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    try! audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord)
    try! audioSession.setActive(true)

    //set up the URL for the audio file
    let documents: AnyObject = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory,  FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, true)[0] as AnyObject
    let str = (documents as! NSString).appending("recordTest.caf")
    NSURL.fileURL(withPath: str as String)


    // make a dictionary to hold the recording settings so we can instantiate our AVAudioRecorder
    let recordSettings: [NSObject : AnyObject] = [AVFormatIDKey as NSObject:kAudioFormatAppleIMA4 as AnyObject,
                                                  AVSampleRateKey as NSObject:44100.0 as AnyObject,
                                                  AVNumberOfChannelsKey as NSObject:2 as AnyObject,AVEncoderBitRateKey as NSObject:12800 as AnyObject,
                                                  AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey as NSObject:16 as AnyObject,
                                                  AVEncoderAudioQualityKey as NSObject:AVAudioQuality.max.rawValue as AnyObject

    ]

    //declare a variable to store the returned error if we have a problem instantiating our AVAudioRecorder
    let error: NSError?

    //Instantiate an AVAudioRecorder
    recorder = try! AVAudioRecorder(url: documents as! URL, settings: recordSettings as! [String : Any])

    //If there's an error, print it - otherwise, run prepareToRecord and meteringEnabled to turn on metering (must be run in that order)
    if let e = error {
        print(e.localizedDescription)
    } else {
        recorder.prepareToRecord()
        recorder.isMeteringEnabled = true

        //start recording
        recorder.record()

        //instantiate a timer to be called with whatever frequency we want to grab metering values
        self.levelTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.02, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.levelTimerCallback), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    }

}

//selector/function is called every time our timer (levelTime) fires
func levelTimerCallback() {
    //update meters
    recorder.updateMeters()

    //print to the console if we are beyond a threshold value
    if recorder.averagePower(forChannel: 0) > -7 {
        print("Mic Blow Detected ")
        print(recorder.averagePower(forChannel: 0))
        isAnimating = false
    } else {
        isAnimating = true
    }
}
```

It also seems that this line is forcing the app to quit so obviously this is where the issue is but I am new to Xcode and cannot spot what I have done wrong, if anyone has ideas on what I should change this too that would be great.

```
recorder = try! AVAudioRecorder(url: documents as! URL, settings: recordSettings as! [String : Any])
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like @ScottThompson has you covered.  Just a tip since it looks like you're new to Swift, force unwrapping an optional (*var*!) should only be done if you're ok with your app crashing if the variable is nil.

Answer (score 2):

You have no code that could have set the value of `error` between the point that it is declared and the point that it is used.  For error possibly take on a new value, it would have to be passed to the constructor for the `AVAudioRecorder`.  You could initialize the error with:

`let error : Error? = nil`

But again this would be frivolous because there is no chance for it's value to change (it is a `let` variable) and even if it were a var, it is not passed to any code between when it is declared and when it is used in the `if let` construction.

You are crashing because you have told the system that you want to create the AVAudioRecorder but it should never fail (that's `try!`).  More likely you want to do something like:

```
let documentSearchPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
let documentsDir = documentSearchPaths[0] as NSString
let recordingFilePath = documentsDir.appendingPathComponent("recordTest.caf")
let recordingFileURL = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: recordingFilePath)

var recorder : AVAudioRecorder?
do{
    let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord)
    try audioSession.setActive(true)

    // make a dictionary to hold the recording settings so we can instantiate our AVAudioRecorder
    let recordSettings: [String : Any] = [AVFormatIDKey : kAudioFormatAppleIMA4,
                                          AVSampleRateKey : NSNumber(value: 44100.0),
                                          AVNumberOfChannelsKey : NSNumber(value: 2),
                                          AVEncoderBitRateKey : NSNumber(value: 12800),
                                          AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey : NSNumber(value: 16),
                                          AVEncoderAudioQualityKey :NSNumber(value: AVAudioQuality.max.rawValue)
    ]

    recorder = try AVAudioRecorder(url: recordingFileURL, settings: recordSettings)
} catch let audio_error as NSError {
    print("Setting up the audio recording failed with error \(audio_error)")
}

if let recorder = recorder {
    recorder.prepareToRecord()
    recorder.isMeteringEnabled = true

    //start recording
    recorder.record()

    //etc...
}
```

Comment: ok thanks, I am now getting a message in the NSLog reading: could not cast value type of NSPathSotre2 to NSUrl. do you have any advice on what I am doing wrong on this line? 'recorder = try! AVAudioRecorder(url: (documents) as! URL, settings: recordSettings as! [String : Any])'

Comment: Try the newly updated code sample I edited into the answer.